# Fastest way to create files in C#

Tags: c#, performance, file, io

I'm running a program to benchmark how fast finding and iterating over all the files in a folder with large numbers of files. The slowest part of the process is creating the 1 million plus files. I'm using a pretty naive method to create the files at the moment:

```
Console.Write("Creating {0:N0} file(s) of size {1:N0} bytes... ", 
    options.FileCount, options.FileSize);
var createTimer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var fileNames = new List<string>();
for (long i = 0; i < options.FileCount; i++)
{
    var filename = Path.Combine(options.Directory.FullName, 
                        CreateFilename(i, options.FileCount));
    using (var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.CreateNew, 
                        FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, 
                        FileOptions.WriteThrough))
    {
        // I have an option to write some data to files, but it's not being used. 
        // That's why there's a using here.
    }
    fileNames.Add(filename);
}
createTimer.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Done.");

// Other code appears here.....

Console.WriteLine("Time to  CreateFiles: {0:N3}sec ({1:N2} files/sec, 1 in {2:N4}ms)"
       , createTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
       , (double)total / createTimer.Elapsed.TotalSeconds
       , createTimer.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds / (double)options.FileCount);
```

Output:

```
Creating 1,000,000 file(s) of size 0 bytes... Done.
Time to  CreateFiles: 9,182.283sec (1,089.05 files/sec, 1 in 9.1823ms)
```

If there anything obviously better than this? I'm looking to test several orders of magnitude larger than 1 million, and it takes a day to create the files!

I havn't tried any sort of parallelism, trying to optimise any file system options or changing the order of file creation.

For completeness, here's the content of `CreateFilename()`:

```
public static string CreateFilename(long i, long totalFiles)
{
    if (totalFiles < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("totalFiles", 
            totalFiles, "totalFiles must be positive");

    // This tries to keep filenames to the 8.3 format as much as possible.
    if (totalFiles < 99999999)
        // No extension.
        return String.Format("{0:00000000}", i);
    else if (totalFiles >= 100000000 && totalFiles < 9999999999)
    {
        // Extend numbers into extension.
        long rem = 0;
        long div = Math.DivRem(i, 1000, out rem);
        return String.Format("{0:00000000}", div) + "." + 
            String.Format("{0:000}", rem);
    }
    else
        // Doesn't fit in 8.3, so just tostring the long.
        return i.ToString();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Tried to parallelise as per StriplingWarrior's suggestion using `Parallel.For()`. Results: about 30 threads thrashing my disk and a net slow down!

```
        var fileNames = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
        var opts = new ParallelOptions();
        opts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;       // 1 thread turns out to be fastest.
        Parallel.For(0L, options.FileCount, opts,
            () => new { Files = new List<string>() },   
            (i, parState, state) =>
            {
                var filename = Path.Combine(options.Directory.FullName, 
                                   CreateFilename(i, options.FileCount));
                using (var file = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.CreateNew
                                  , FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None
                                  , 4096, FileOptions.WriteThrough))
                {
                }
                fileNames.Add(filename);
                return state;
            },
            state => 
            {
                foreach (var f in state.Files)
                {
                    fileNames.Add(f);
                }
            });
        createTimer.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

Found that changing the `FileOptions` in the `FileStream` improved perf by ~50%. Seems I was turning off any write cache.

```
new FileStream(filename, FileMode.CreateNew, 
                 FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 
                 4096, FileOptions.None)
```

Results:

```
Creating 10,000 file(s) of size 0 bytes... Done.
Time to  CreateFiles: 12.390sec (8,071.05 files/sec, 1 in 1.2390ms)
```

Other ideas still welcome.

Comment: Do you have to write them all to a single directory? If you can break it to say 1000 files in 1000 directories things may well be faster.

Comment: How about using C? By the way, I think there will be limitations if you uses HDD. SSD may help speed up things a bit.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is almost certainly a limit of your particular disk/filesystem, not C#.  The SSD solution would help, for sure.

Comment: @user482594: I doubt (though haven't tried) that "Use C" is a useful answer here.  The C# file operations are simple wrappers around Win32 methods already, you're not paying much in terms of overhead as Disk IO is going to be your bottleneck by a large margin.

Comment: @oded - yes. That's the point of the benchmark, to see how bad perf gets when your directory has a bazillion files in it. Any sane person would either a) shard it like you suggest or b) use a database.

Comment: @ChrisShain - I'm benching on a mechanical HDD at the moment. I'll try an SSD at some point in the future (and expect performance to be better, although lots of small writes might not do so well).

Comment: Random thought: could NTFS's transactional file system help? Is there a c# interface to it somewhere?

Comment: @ligos Nice thought, but I dont think so in this case.  I assume you were going for "copy on modify" semantics, which unfortunately NTFS doesn't have, other than for Shadow Copy.

Comment: @ChrisShain Thanks for the advice on transactional FS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way I found was a simple loop around `File.Create()`:

```
IEnumerable filenames = GetFilenames();
foreach (var filename in filenames)
{
    File.Create(filename);
}
```

Which is equivalent to (what I'm actually using in code):

```
IEnumerable filenames= GetFilenames();
foreach (var filename in filenames)
{
    new FileStream(filename, FileMode.CreateNew, 
             FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 
             4096, FileOptions.None)
}
```

And if you actually want to write something to the file:

```
IEnumerable filenames= GetFilenames();
foreach (var filename in filenames)
{
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.CreateNew, 
             FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 
             4096, FileOptions.None))
    {
        // Write something to your file.
    }
}
```

Things that don't seem to help:

- Parallelism in the form of `Parallel.ForEach()` or `Parallel.For()`. This produces a net slowdown which gets worse as the number of threads increase.
- According to StriplingWarrior, an SSD. Haven't tested myself (yet), but I speculate this may be because there are so many small writes.

Answer (score 10):

Your biggest bottleneck here is undoubtedly your hard drive. In some quick testing, I was able to see some significant performance improvements (but not orders of magnitude) by taking advantage of parallelism:

```
Parallel.For(1, 10000,
    i => File.Create(Path.Combine(path, i.ToString())));
```

Interestingly enough, on my machine at least, an SSD does not seem to make a big difference for this operation.

- On my HDD, the above code creates 100,000 files in roughly 31 seconds.
- On my SDD, the above code creates 100,000 files in roughly 33 seconds.

## Update

A decade years later, with updated hardware and .NET 6, I decided to test a few different strategies with benchmarking. [LINQPad Script](http://share.linqpad.net/lulcoc.linq)

Surprisingly, the `Parallel.For` approach seems to take about 1/3 the time. Trying to leverage concurrency via WriteAllTextAsync had no significant impact.

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not getting any speedup from using `Parallel.For()`. But your code does run quicker. Must be something else....

Comment: Ah!! `File.Create()` is an order of magnitude faster than creating a new `FileStream`.

Comment: @ligos: I'm glad to hear that helped. Odd how it's the simple, unexpected things that sometimes make all the difference. :-)

Comment: Oh, and it looks like calling `Close()`/`Dispose()` on the `FileStream` returned from `File.Create()` has a little overhead too. Ends up passing `FileOptions.None` to `FileStream` constructor is faster. I'm creating ~8k files / sec now.

Comment: It's unlikely that the `Parallel.For` would help, since the primary bottleneck *should be* the file system. But I can see where `File.Create` would be faster than `FileStream.Create`.

Comment: @JimMischel - I checked the .NET 4 source for `File.Create()`, it just creates a `FileStream`, all the action is in the `FileStream` constructor. But that's where I picked up my error with `FileOptions`.

Comment: @ligos: Good find. You should create and accept an answer to that effect. I think people would be interested to see how they can most quickly create files.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior +1 from me for suggesting parallelism, but I've added my own answer (which I can't accept for 24 hours!). I guess that's time for someone else to improve on it!