# Best way to create a lot of small files?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, createfile

I want to create a lot (1 million) small files as quickly as possible, that's what I'm doing now:

```
for(long i = 0; i < veryVeryLong; i++){
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.None)) {
        byte[] bytes = GetFileContent(i); // no matter
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
}
```

Can I speed up?

**UPDATE**

roomaroo right, I need to use Parallel, but I combined it with my function and this has a much better result. Code:

```
Parallel.For(0, veryVeryLogn, (i) => {
    using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.None)) {
        byte[] bytes = GetFileContent(i); // no matter
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
});
```

Comment: You could something in parallel.

Comment: not sure if can help you.. but there is a command line utils to create files.. "fsutil file createnew"

Comment: Since you're using C#, you might want to look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979686/fastest-way-to-create-files-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: Yes, I have long been looking for an answer and saw that post, but I was much more speed reduction.

Comment: With parallel end up working more slowly

Comment: Profile and see where it is slow. Otherwise buy SSD and enjoy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ChrisBint suggested, use a parallel loop.

I created three methods to write the files (code below). One uses your code above, one uses File.WriteAllBytes(...) - both these use a traditional for loop.

The third implementation used a parallel for loop.

Here are the times to create 1000 files:

> FileStream: 2658ms
>
> File.WriteAllBytes: 2555ms
>
> Parallel.For: 617ms

So the parallel loop is four times faster than the slowest implementation. Obviously this will vary on different hardware, and your results will depend very much on your CPU and disk.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FileCreator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string folder = @"d:\temp";

            Clean(folder);
            CreateWithParallelFileWriteBytes(folder);

            Clean(folder);
            CreateWithFileStream(folder);

            Clean(folder);
            CreateWithFileWriteBytes(folder);
        }

        private static void Clean(string folder)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(folder))
            {
                Directory.Delete(folder, true);
            }

            Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);
        }

        private static byte[] GetFileContent(int i)
        {
            Random r = new Random(i);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            r.NextBytes(buffer);
            return buffer;
        }

        private static void CreateWithFileStream(string folder)
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(folder, string.Format("file{0}.dat", i));

                using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.None))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = GetFileContent(i);
                    fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Time for CreateWithFileStream: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        private static void CreateWithFileWriteBytes(string folder)
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(folder, string.Format("file{0}.dat", i));
                File.WriteAllBytes(path, GetFileContent(i));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Time for CreateWithFileWriteBytes: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        private static void CreateWithParallelFileWriteBytes(string folder)
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();

            Parallel.For(0, 1000, (i) =>
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(folder, string.Format("file{0}.dat", i));
                File.WriteAllBytes(path, GetFileContent(i));
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Time for CreateWithParallelFileWriteBytes: {0}ms", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a change in the times if you run the parallel version first?  The createfile is sometimes faster if the file is already on disk.

Comment: Doesn't seem to affect the times. It's still ~600ms for the parallel version.

Comment: I've updated to code so it deletes the output folder between each test to make things fairer. The times are much the same (2715ms/2608ms/602ms).

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this result is only observed in a small number of files (<3000). When I increased the number to 10,000, my function worked faster. But I want to make a million)

Comment: @Slovo - I've just run the tests with 100000 files. The parallel version takes 66s, standard for loop with FileStream takes 240s and with File.WriteAllBytes takes 238s. BUT I have got a crazy fast 8 core Xeon CPU which will make a big difference to the parallel version.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the first time a parallel running long, but then a very stable and fast, thanks for the advice! I'm working on a laptop with intel core i5.

Comment: The Parallel For approach worked great for me, thank you.  For a set of 100,000 files, it cut the time from 322 seconds to 70 seconds.  In my case, each file is very small, and each has different contents.